Tailored colors in stacked column chart
I am struggling to find how I can change the colors of my stacked column chart. The settings only seem to allow for colors per disaggregation level (Households at risk - Households not at risk). I want each column to have a different color, so G0 - G1 - G2 - G3 should be colored differently. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

